# Gatsby graphql query for json data with an empty array throws an error

Tags: javascript, json, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to query some JSON data that may contain an empty array, the JSON file will be accessible via CMS so it must support being empty, however, when gatsby attempts to query an empty array it throws an error (assumably as I'm trying to query items inside an object inside the array).

Is there a way in Gatsby to query a JSON file but expect the array to be empty? (make the objects inside optional?).

Here's my dilemma in code:

`careers.json`

```
{
    "title": "Careers",
    "subtitle": "Looking for an exciting new career change?",
    "jobs": [
        {
            "title": "Job 01",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor."
        }
    ]
}
```

The above JSON property `jobs` will also be an empty array when there aren't any jobs, like so:

```
{
    "title": "Careers",
    "subtitle": "Looking for an exciting new career change?",
    "jobs": []
}
```

However, when I attempt to query this in my Gatsby page, it throws an error:

```
export const query = graphql`
    query {
       careersJson {
            title
            subtitle
            jobs {
                title
                description
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot query field "jobs" on type "CareersJson".

GraphQL request:27:13
26 |             subtitle
27 |             jobs {
   |             ^
28 |                 title
```

[graphql empty array error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfQ3u.png)

Comment: The issue stems from the fact that an empty array is returned as null. This will depend on how you obtain your JSON data from the API. In this post a user mentions setting the schema for that particular value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112661/return-empty-array-instead-of-null-in-graphql-api. I'm not all that experienced with graphql to tell you how to do that. Instead if you can tweak the API to return an empty string instead of an empty array, it won't return an error. Hopefully someone more experienced can shed some light into this.